# Binary to character matrix help

Tags: java, binary, character

FYI: This is a practice homework exercise. I've been working on it, but now I'm stuck. Any tips/help would be appreciated. I've been staring at it a while and no progress has been made.

Summarized question:
Nine coins are place in a 3x3 matrix with some face up and some face down. Heads = 0 and tails = 1. Each state can also be represented using a binary number. There are 512 possibilities. Problem: Write a program that asks user for a number between 0-511 and displays corresponding matrix with characters H and T like this:

User enters number 7 (which is 000000111 or HHHHHHTTT)
Display should be:
H H H
H H H
T T T

This is what I have so far. I'm not asking for the answer necessarily, I would just like a push in the right direction. Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class converting {
    public static void main(String[] ar) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a number between 0 and 511: ");

        int number = s.nextInt();
        if(number <= 511 && number > 0)
        {
             String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(number);
             String tails = bin.replace('1', 'T');

         int count = 0;
         char[] arr = tails.toCharArray();

         for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            System.out.print(arr[i]);
            count++;
            if (count == 3) {
                System.out.println();
                count = 0;
            }
        }
      }
      else{
        System.out.print("Please enter a number between 0 and 511\n");
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're really close. Some notes:

- `Scanner#nextInt` can throw exceptions; handle them gracefully.
- You need to check that `number` is in range (0-511).
- Once you have `bin`, you have 1-9 binary digits -- `0`s and `1`s. You want to make sure you have exactly 9 of them, so insert any missing `0`s at the front.
- You now have 9 `0`s and `1`s; you want `H`s and `T`s. Check out [`String#replace`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)).
- You now have a string with 9 `H`s and `T`s. Output it in three lines, three chars per line. Check out [`String#substring`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added a check for valid numbers
    if(number <= 511 && number > 0). 
I also tried using replace and I got it to work for T:
    String tails = bin.replace('1', 'T');
My question now is how can I replace all F's with 0's. My char array is currently char[] arr = tails.toCharArray(); which only has the replaced 1's. Does that make sense?

Is there a way to update my first post with the code I have now?

Comment: Ok. Updated first post. Thanks!

Comment: @relyt: Shouldn't that `> 0` be `>= 0`? Or is the user not allowed to have a board that's all `H`s?

Answer (score 1):

> intToString.toCharArray();

This should be `bin.toCharArray()`, methinks.

What else are you having problems with?

Answer (score 1):

`String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` may be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

I would use StringBuilder to build up the "board", and only print it out afterwards.

I would create a method called "createBoard" that has as parameters the number, the width and the depth. Always program for flexibility.

I would use two counters, say x and y that iterate through the width and depth (a simple for next loop suffices). position = x * width + y

I would use BigInteger.valueOf() and use BigInteger.testBit(position).

I would make really sure that my code looks nice and has comments in.

Comment: Maarten, I'm sure this is probably a good way to do it, but at this point I think it's over my head. As I learn more this may make sense to me. Thanks for the response though.